# error in switch function in R

Tags: r, switch-statement

```
              to_select=cbind(te_matrix[i,j],te_matrix[j,k],te_matrix[i,k]);
          te_ac=apply(abs(to_select),2,sort);
          var_ac=apply(abs(to_select),2,order);
          if(te_ac[1]<te_ac[2]-0.005){
            switch(var_ac[1],
                    1= (del_arc<-rbind(del_arc,cbind(count-1,i,k)))
                    2= (del_arc<-rbind(del_arc,cbind(count-1,j,k)))
                    3= (del_arc<-rbind(del_arc,cbind(count-1,i,k))))
          }
```

when I run this code, it throws error as followed:

```
M:/学习/毕业设计/传递熵R语言/triplenode.R:27:26: unexpected '='
26:                 switch(var_ac[1],
27:                         1=
                             ^
```

Did I make any mistake about the function "switch" in R

Comment: try quoting your numbers, like `"1" = (...`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work!

Comment: 'code in   M:/学习/毕业设计/传递熵R语言/triplenode.R:28:25: unexpected string constant
27:                         "1" = (del_arc<-rbind(del_arc,cbind(count-1,i,k)))
28:                         "2"
                            ^'

Comment: Commas must separate each value/statement pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The switch function operates differently if the switching expression is numeric.  Your switching expression is a number.

Since your switching expression is number, you don't need the = signs.

In either case, you also need commas separating the options

```
switch(var_ac[1],
         del_arc<-rbind(del_arc,cbind(count-1,i,k)),
         del_arc<-rbind(del_arc,cbind(count-1,j,k)),
         del_arc<-rbind(del_arc,cbind(count-1,i,k))
       )
```

The value of your `var_ac[1]` must evaluate (or be coerced) to the value 1,2, or 3, or the switch function will return `NULL`